# Exclude term in elasticsearch_dsl filter query

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

What is the dsl query syntax to exclude a term from a filter query? In this example below, how would i modify the query to include everything in field except "yes"?

```
s = s.filter('terms', field=['yes'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
s = s.exclude('terms', field=['yes'])
```

Comment: It would help OP and other SO users if you can add a description of your code.

Comment: Hello Honza, I did try that earlier but it gave AttributeError: 'Search' object has no attribute 'exclude'. Now I realized I was working with a 2.x version, just updated to 5.x and it works. So thanks!